# How to remove a space between matching words?

Tags: regex, linux, bash, replace, sed

I've read a lot of questions about how to replace spaces from a file but I have the following problem:

I have a file like so:

```
<foo>"crazy foo"</foo> <bar>dull-bar</bar>
```

and I'm trying to remove spaces between `> <` and only those ones so the file would be like:

```
`<foo>"crazy foo"</foo><bar>dull-bar</bar>`
```

So far I've tried to remove then by using `sed` and `tr`. Sed is not working by any chance and using `tr '> <' '><'` outputs:

```
<foo>"crazy foo"</foo><<bar>dull-bar</bar>
```

Comment: have you tried `echo '<foo>"crazy foo"</foo> <bar>dull-bar</bar>' | sed 's/> </></g'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
sed -i -e "s/> *</></g" YourFile
```

`-i` means `YourFile` is modified. Remove this option to test your command and display the result in shell output.

`*` matches `n` spaces.

The `g` at the end of sed expression means "Replace all the occurrences".

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this

```
echo "<foo>"crazy foo"</foo> <bar>dull-bar</bar>" | sed 's/>[[:space:]]*</></g '
```

Answer (score 0):

```
awk -F"\"" '{print $3}' file.txt | sed 's/ //g'
```